# How to get Laravel Passport oauth_client from request?

Tags: laravel-passport

I have different frontend websites from which users can sign in through **Laravel Passport** on my backend website. Each frontend has its own `oauth_client` entry (`id`, `name` and `secret`).

The backend is currently only returning user information this way:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->load('foo');
});
```

How to check from which website or `oauth_client` the request comes from (in order to load the correct `foo`) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Oauth client ID** and **redirect URI** are available from:

```
$request->user()->token()->client;
```